# Как добавить товар в корзины на яваскрипте?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
var shopping = document.getElementById('shopping-basket-place');
var ourList = document.getElementById("our-list");
var ourButton = document.getElementById('our-button');
var ourHeadline = document.getElementById('our-headline');
var listItems = document.querySelectorAll('li');

for (var i = listItems.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  listItems[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    // alert('Click detected!');
    ourHeadline.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
  });
}


ourButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  // create New List
  shopping.innerHTML += this.innerHTML + "Something New" + " ,     ";
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.buttonAdd {
  background-color: #7290bf;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  transform: skewX(-20deg);
  border: 0;
  box-shadow: 5px 10px 3px;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.nav-li {
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.nav-li li {
  padding: 0 20px;
  margin: 15px 0 15px 10px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

h1 {
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.thumbnail {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin-left: 350px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/basscss/8.0.10/css/basscss.min.css">
<h1 id="our-headline">Кликните на товаре чтобы добавить его в корзину</h1>
<!--Click a list item to replace this text. -->
<button class="buttonAdd" id="our-button">Add new item</button>
<div class="nav-li">
  <ul id="our-list">
    <li>Бейсболка <span class="thumbnail overflow-hidden"><img  src="https://media.decathlon.in/3598688-home_default/trek-100-mountain-trekking-cap-blue.jpg" alt=""></span></li>
    <li>Second item</li>
    <li>Third item</li>
    <li>Fourth item</li>
    <li>Fifth item</li>
  </ul>
  <img src="https://banner2.kisspng.com/20180329/uwq/kisspng-computer-icons-contract-of-sale-trade-shopping-car-cart-5abd43eb33e7d9.5315293915223531312126.jpg" alt="" style="width:50px; height: 50px;" class="relative"><span style="margin-left: 35px; font-size:25px;position:relative;">Корзина</span>

  <div style="max-width: 100%; height: 200px; background-color: #fcfcfc; border: 1px solid #e2e2e2; margin: 20px">>
    <p id="shopping-basket-place"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Ребята, помогите с сайтом, а именно с `JS`. Когда я нажимаю на список `(Бейсболка, thing 1, thing 2,.. etc.)` Надо чтобы товар появлялся в блоке корзина, тоже самое что если нажать на верхнюю кнопку `Add new item`.

Спасибо.

Comment: Пожалуйста, отредактируйте заголовок на более информативный.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я правильно понял

Просто повешай класс к li

Например

```
<li class="add">Second item</li>

$('.add').click(function () {
  $('#shopping-basket-place').append($(this).text());
});
```

Если в дальнейшем тебе нужно будет удалить товар из корзины, то лучше сначала помещай весь товар в массив, а потом выводи в блок